# DB2 - question regarding RESTORE OFFLINE backup and Archive Logs

Tags: backup, db2, logs, restore

I configured last night DB2 to be in Archive Mode.
I created required offline backup at 23:00 last night.
First online backup will be created at Friday night.
Archive logs now keep coming to the archive log location which is OK.

My question is:
can I use restore operation (ROLLFORWARD also) for combination with OFFLINE backup and Archive Logs  or ROLLFORWARD operation can be used only for combination ONLINE backup+Archive Logs???

I am confused little with that.

So my question is can I do the restore of offline backup last night and ROLLFORWARD for example archive logs to the point of time today at 10 A.M.?

Is this possible or no? If this is possible what will be the command?Will it be different like when restoring Online Backup+Archive Logs???

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can issue `ROLLFORWARD` after restoring an offline backup. The `ROLLFORWARD` command syntax remains the same, regardless of the type of restored backup image.

Comment: thank you mustaccio... if I can ask you one more thing - can I do the rollforward if I do not have active logs? My plan is to test restore on second backup database server: I would like to do the restore of offline backup + rollforward of archive logs which I will copy on another server... So I suppose I will be able to do it just for testing purposes on second server with offline backup and archive logs right? I do not need transaction logs (active logs)?

Comment: @Dejan - Whether or not you have active logs or take an online or offline backup, once you are using archivable logging, you need to rollforward to take the database out of rollforward pending mode.

Comment: Active logs are no different from the archived logs, except may be by their location. You will be able to roll forward to the latest point in time in whatever logs you have available.

Comment: @ChrisAldrich -- that's not exactly true. The "rollforward pending" state has no dependency on archive or circular logging. A restored database will by default be placed in the "rollforward pending" state regardless of the backup mode or logging configuration. However, when restoring an _offline_ backup you have an option to avoid that by specifying the `without rolling forward` clause during the restore; this clause is invalid when restoring an online backup.

Comment: So this clause "without rolling forward" cannot be used when restoring online backup image?right? when restoring online backup image rollforward operation is required right?